# Translucent effect to section of webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for my webpage and I have this

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="front">
         <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.front{
    background-color:silver;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

The width & height of div is 200px,200px.I want the area covered by the div element to be translucent ie. showing the blur background, but the text that div contains should be clear as well. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need a [rgba](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()) background:

```
background-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.5);
```

> Colors can be defined in the Red-green-blue-alpha model (RGBa) using
>   the rgba() functional notation. RGBa extends the RGB color model to
>   include the alpha channel, allowing specification of the opacity of a
>   color. a means opacity: 0=transparent; 1=opaque;

Comment: should really have an rgb fallback in case rgba isn't supported by the browser

Comment: Yeah, and a fallback for people who don't have a browser. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add `opacity: 0.5;` to your css class.

Answer (score 1):

you can use opacity for the background-image and use [before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) Selector to remain the opacity of the text:

like this:

```css
.front {
  z-index: 1;
}
.front:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url("http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/23-animation-wallpaper.preview.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.font > p {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<div class="front">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/b9mt5gvq/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rgba for the background image since adding opacity would apply it for the text in the div also.

```
background-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.5);
```

but this is not supported in IE.

So you can have a transparent background image created and applied using background-image property.

Answer (score 0):

try this css :

```
.front{
     background-color:silver;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Increase or decrease opacity according to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Using opacity in CSS is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  little out of the box, you can really **blur** your image if you try a little different mark-up.

Here it goes

```css
.front{
    background-color:silver;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
     -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    z-index:0;
}
.back{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="front"></div>
  <div class="back">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</body>
```